# Let $f: G \to H$ be a homomorphism and $g \in G. $ If $o(g)=n$ is finite, then $o(f(g)) | o(g).$ If $f$ is an isomorphism, then $o(f(g)) =o(g)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

May I verify if my proof to the a/m claim is correct? Thank you.

Let $e_G, e_H$ be identity elements of $(G,*_1)$ and $(H,*_2)$.

Note that $f(e_G)*_2f(x) = f(x) , \forall x\in G.$ Then $e_H*_2f(x) = f(e_G)*_2f(x) \implies f(e_G) = e_H.$

Now, $f(g^n) = $ $f(g*_1g*_1....*_1 g) = f(g) *_2 f(g)*_2...*_2f(g) = e_H $ $\implies (f(g))^n =e_H \implies o(f(g)) | n.  $ If $f$ is an isomorphism, then $\exists $ isomorphism $f':H\to G. $ By above proof, $o(f(g)) = m < \infty.$

Then, $f'((f(g))^m)= $ $f'(f(g)) *_1 f'(f(g))*_1 ... *_1 f'(f(g)) = g^m =e_G \implies n | m. (qed)$

Comment: This is correct, well done!

Answer (score 1):

Proving that $f(1)=1$ is not necessary, because it holds for every group homomorphism:
$$
f(1)=f(1\,1)=f(1)f(1)
$$
and therefore
$$
1=f(1)(f(1))^{-1}=f(1)f(1)(f(1))^{-1}=f(1)
$$

Note 1: we only use the fact that $H$ is a group.

Note 2: distinguishing the neutral elements and the operations is not needed, the context always tells you which is which.

The verification of the claim depends on what definition of order of an element you're using. But once you have proved the lemma

> If $G$ is a group and $x\in G$, if $x^n=1$ for $n>1$, then $x$ has finite order and $n\mid o(x)$

you have the tools you need. So your proof is correct apart from a minor detail: the homomorphism $f'\colon H\to G$ can be taken to be the inverse map of $f$, so that $f'(f(x))=x$.